# output current of Wilson mirror

Tags: differential, current-mirror

I am trying to drive the output current Iout but I am not getting what it is shown on the graph.
Can you have a look and let me know what I got wrong please? Thanks

[image]

here is my attempt
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't checked any other calculations other than this:

[image]

The two circled expressions are clearly not equal.

But if you simply multiply top and bottom with the same thing, like this:
\$ \frac{\beta + 1}{\beta + 1} \$ then you get the expression you are looking for.

Comment: they are correct because it is a current mirror. the emitter current of Q3 is equal to collector current of Q1 + base current of Q1 .

Comment: One should never assign or reuse a variable name for more than one quantities in the same analysis. It is sloppy and confusing. I now see what you were doing and I believe the printed expression next to the schematic is wrong.